# vb.net PrintPage Unreadable Text When Printing Receipt

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printing, receipt

When printing a receipt the text will become unreadable and not print correctly.

It's suppose to count the different bill denominations and print out how many of each bill. 
Example: 
Count  Denomination
12      $5
16      $10
8       $20
13      $100

We've had this same issue a couple of times and if I'm not mistaken it always happens when it tries to print the number of $20 bills. This issue does not happen very often, it's very rare.

Here is some sample code

```
    Dim billCountPlacement As Integer = e.PageBounds.Left + 35
    Dim billAmountPlacement As Integer = e.PageBounds.Left + 100
    For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvBillCounts.Items
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lvi.SubItems(1).Text, textFont, Brushes.Black, billCountPlacement, y)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lvi.SubItems(0).Text, textFont, Brushes.Black, billAmountPlacement, y, rightFormat)
        y += lineSpacing
    Next
    y += lineSpacing * 2
```

[part of the receipt]https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSr8B.png

Any ideas on why the receipt text would get all jumbled like that.

- We have already tried replacing the printer and the issue came back.
- I've done multiple test prints and never gotten the issue.

Comment: A printer driver bug, perhaps.  Not unlikely, nobody ever actually uses it.  Receipt printers are too slow to be useable with the driver, boilerplate is to bypass it and send commands directly to the printer.

Comment: Our tech support department went in and updated the driver to the newest version. I believe he said the old version was about 4 versions behind.

We're gonna give it a week or so and see if we have any more issues. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Print to a file (together with the printer control settings like double-strike, double-width, double-height, etc.) and send the file to the printer. See this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322090) for the how-to. Note that control settings commands may vary for each printer.